# Spark: refer to a column dynamically based on the value of another column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset with many fields and one of the fields "valuefieldname" is the a reference/pointer column which contains the field_name of the field which should be processed. How can I dynamically fetch that column value based on the "valuefieldname" column?

I need something similar to the below code (which doesn't work)

```
val dataSet2 = dataSet1.withColumn("targetoutput", col(col("valuefieldname")))
```

Comment: Adding sample input and expected output would be helpful here

Comment: For each row, the content of "valuefieldname" is going to be different? Or you have in all that column like a literal value in all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to refer to a column dynamically yet directly in a Spark plan. Therefore, the dynamic access has to happen either via a data structure that is part of the plan or via more than one plan. This leads to three strategies for solving the problem:

1. Use a UDF to dynamically address a field in a `Row`. This is the most general and easiest approach. It works best when there aren't too many columns and/or when the data is sparse.
2. Build a `MapType` column and reference it. In some cases, this can be more efficient that (1).
3. Make multiple (light) passes through the data and union the results. Best used when the number of columns is small and the data in each column is "heavy", e.g., deeply structured data, and dense.

Here is how to do (1):

```
def getColumnAs[A](colName: String, row: Row): Option[A] = 
  if (row == null) None
  else {
    val idx = row.fieldIndex(colName)
    if (row.isNullAt(idx)) None else Some(row.getAs[A](idx))
  }

case class Data(col_name: String, x: Option[Int], y: Option[Int])

val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  Data("x", Some(1), None), 
  Data("x", Some(2), Some(20)), 
  Data("y", None,    Some(30))
)).toDF

val colValue = udf(getColumnAs[Int] _)

df.select(
    'col_name, 
    colValue('col_name, struct('*)).as("col_value")
  )
  .show
```

The output is

```
+--------+---------+
|col_name|col_value|
+--------+---------+
|       x|        1|
|       x|        2|
|       y|       30|
+--------+---------+
```